# undefined method `simple_form_for' in RoR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I've been browsing stack overflow and I noticed that many people use simple_form to make their lives easier.

I wanted to give it a try, so I added the gem to my gem file (`gem 'simple_form'`) and sent:

```
rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap
```

After reading the installation message, I created a view with the sample code from the readme:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :username %>
  <%= f.input :password %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Unfortunately, I get this error as soon as I try to load the page:

```
undefined method `simple_form_for' for #<#<Class:0x69dd688>:0x6903ac8>
```

What gives? How come it can't even recognize the method? I feel like I'm missing something really simply here. Could it be because i'm using bootstrap-sass? Do I need to include a helper in my user controller?

Comment: did you restart server after install `simple_form` gem?

Comment: doh! of course. I knew it was something silly like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 59):

Did you restart your server? 
Always keep in mind that after you install a gem or plugin. 
Always restart your server

Answer (score 8):

Its all because you didn't restart your server after installing new libraries such as simple_form, devise etc.

Try stop your server and restart it. Your code is perfect!. I encountered this several times. The solution is just restarting the server!.

Comment: Compared to the most upvoted and older answer, this does not provide any additional insight.

Answer (score 3):

You must restart your server after installing `simple_form` gem.

Comment: Compared to the most upvoted and much older answer, this does not provide any additional insight.

Answer (score 0):

For any absolute beginners. This error will occur if you forgot to install `simple_form`. To rectify, add this to your Gemfile

```
gem 'simple_form'
```

and `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

To summarize all possibilities from above, hopefully this list is useful for other gems too.

1. Check if the `simple_form` gem is installed correctly

   Find the gem in `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`. Another way is to run this command in your terminal: `bundle list | grep simple_form`
2. If the output is empty

   Possibly `simple_form` isn't installed in your project yet. Since the gem is an external gem, it isn't included in the Rails framework. Rails has its own form library (aka `form_with` and `form_for`).

   To add `simple_form` to your project, open the Gemfile and add `gem 'simple_form'`, then run the command in your terminal `bundle install`.
3. If the output isn't empty

   Check if you have restart the server yet.
4. After restart the server, and you still not be able to access `SimpleForm` constant

   Check if the gem is set to `require: false` in Gemfile. If so, remove this part and run `bundle install`.
5. You can check if the gem is loaded from rails console by typing `rails console` or `rails c` in your terminal.

   After the console is loaded, type `SimpleForm` and hit Enter. In the case there is some errors complaining about the constant is undefined, refer to previous steps to fix.